# Turning off Content Approval in SharePoint without losing data

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have document library that has been utilizing SharePoint's 'Content Approval' feature. We had been using this for sending approvals to the "approvers" however have been running into frequent "etag mismatch" errors. There has been no consistency for when the error appears so we wanted to go the route of not doing it through the content approval feature as that has been causing issues.

The issue however is we have used this way for a long time and utilize the "Approval status" column which is tied to the content approval. So if we turn off the feature we lose all of that data.

Is it possible to transition that data to a new column that we have created?

Tried creating a column with the same name and JSON to see if it would populate with our data but it did not.

Comment: You will have to create a new column (text or choice) and update column value for each row using Power automate or PowerShell (one time activity).

Answer (score 0):

To turn off Content Approval in SharePoint without losing data, you can create a new column and copy the data from the "Approval status" column to the new column. Unfortunately, it is not possible to transition that data to a new column that has the same name and JSON.